# Android SDK Manager complains with "Loading SDK component information failed."

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I would like to build mobile apps using Xamarin and Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (15.8.4). I therefor followed Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-ch/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/installation/windows) on installing the whole stack. I choose the `Mobile Development with .NET` workload from the installer, expecting it to pull in all the necessary dependencies.

Unfortunately when I try to launch the Android SDK Manager from within Visual Studio i get `Loading SDK component information failed. Please retry`.

[image]

According to the documentation the VS installer should install AndroidNDK to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64`. This folder is available, but empty.

However I found the folder `C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64` on my filesystem containing `android-ndk-r13b` and `android-ndk-r15c`. I tried pointing to one of this directory from VS `Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android NDK Location` without a change to my aforementioned problem.

[image]

The following packages are installed:

Section emulators:

- Google Android-Emulator (API-Level 27)
- Intel Hardware Accel Exec Manager (HAXM) (global installation)

Development activities:

- F# Language Support
- Xamarin
- Xamarin Profiler
- Xamarin Remoted Simulator
- Xamarin Workbooks

SDKs, Libs and frameworks:

- Android NDK (R13B)
- Android NDK (R15C)
- Android SDK-Setup (API-Level 27)
- JDK (8.0.1120.15)

**What am I doing wrong here? Is there any package missing?**

**[Edit1]**

- Please note: I am not behind a company firewall/proxy, so network should be no issue
- The same happens when switching to the Google Repository
- Launching Visual Studio as local Administrator makes no difference
- Also repairing Visual Studio did not solve the issue..

**[Edit2]**

- Also I can't start the `Android Device Manager`. Nor from VS nor directly from the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\AndroidDeviceManager` -
  yes, tried as local administrator... what the heck

**[Edit3]**

- I just found out by accident, that when running `AndroidSdkManager.exe` non evaluated it works!!! So there must be some permission issue, maybe NTFS rights. Will check and report back.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? Or is there any updates about this issue?

Comment: After spending hours of hours in trying to solve this I decided to do a fresh install of my workstation which "solved" the issues...

Comment: glad to hear that. Any more question about Xamarin issue in VS, it will be better  if you could report it via  click VS `Help` --> `Send Feedback` --> `Report a Problem`. :)

Comment: There's information that changing the repository to Google in SDK Manager settings could help. Possibly a more lightweight solution than reinstalling Windows.

Answer (score 9):

Changing the repository settings to Google worked for me. So, on android SDK manager click on the gear icon (settings), then Repository -> Google.

@Alexandr Zarubkin- Thanks for the input it helped me.

Comment: Wow, thanks SO MUCH.  I kept seeing people saying to set the Repository to google but had no idea how to do that.  Your suggestion pointed me to the right place and it's working.  Installing the platforms I want.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have the option to choose a Google repo, but this did give me a clue. My connection failed immediately which made me suspicious about DNS resolution. I run pihole DNS filtering and found that some blacklist entry was blocking the connection. I disabled pihole temporarily and the problem resolved.